# keep N number of duplicate rows (based on column 1)

Tags: awk, grep, duplicates

I have a csv with this first column of indexes:

```
TTTGACTCATCCGATA-1-H0025_apex 
TTTGATCTCAAGGCTT-1-H0025_apex
TTTGGAGAGTTTGAGA-1-H0025_apex
TTTGGAGGTAAGATAC-1-H0025_apex
TTTGGTTCAAGTGACG-1-H0025_apex
TTTGGTTTCACTTCTA-1-H0025_apex
TTTGGTTTCTTTCTAG-1-H0025_apex
TTTGTTGCAACATACC-1-H0025_apex
AAACCCAAGCATATGA-1-H0025_LA
AAACCCACAAGGCTTT-1-H0025_LA
AAACCCACACACTTAG-1-H0025_LA
AAACCCATCGCGTAGC-1-H0025_LA
AAACGAAAGTAAGCAT-1-H0025_LA
AAACGAAAGTATGTAG-1-H0025_LA
AAACGAAAGTGCACAG-1-H0025_LA
AAACGAAGTAGTTCCA-1-H0025_LA
AAACGAAGTGTTCCAA-1-H0025_LA
AAACGAAGTTGCATAC-1-H0025_LA
```

I need to filter the rows to keep only 3 copies of the duplicated lines ( the lines are not duplicated but only a substring of the index is duplicated as you can see form the index). I have hundreds of duplicated indexes and I need to take only the first 3 occurrances per each occurrance. I was thinking to do it with `grep -m=3` after creating a list of unique indexes names to use for a grep loop.
do you have a faster solution? maybe with awk?
thanks

Comment: Which character is the field separator? `-` or `_` or something else? Add expected output for the given sample

Comment: Please show your desired output in your question.

Comment: Please show truly representative sample input CSV, not just a standalone column from the input.

Comment: `awk -F, 'a[substr($1,17)]++<3' in.csv >out.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change your example to have numbered duplicates:

```
TTTGACTCATCCGATA-1-H0025_apex 1
TTTGATCTCAAGGCTT-1-H0025_apex 1
TTTGGAGAGTTTGAGA-1-H0025_apex
TTTGATCTCAAGGCTT-1-H0025_apex 2
TTTGGTTCAAGTGACG-1-H0025_apex
TTTGACTCATCCGATA-1-H0025_apex 2
TTTGTTGCAACATACC-1-H0025_apex
TTTGACTCATCCGATA-1-H0025_apex 3
AAACCCAAGCATATGA-1-H0025_LA
TTTGATCTCAAGGCTT-1-H0025_apex 3
AAACCCACACACTTAG-1-H0025_LA
TTTGACTCATCCGATA-1-H0025_apex 4
AAACCCATCGCGTAGC-1-H0025_LA
TTTGATCTCAAGGCTT-1-H0025_apex 4
AAACGAAAGTATGTAG-1-H0025_LA
AAACGAAAGTGCACAG-1-H0025_LA
TTTGACTCATCCGATA-1-H0025_apex 5
TTTGATCTCAAGGCTT-1-H0025_apex 5
```

With awk you can do (assuming the contents of `$1` is the key defining a 'duplicate'):

```
awk '++cnt[$1]<=3' file  
TTTGACTCATCCGATA-1-H0025_apex 1
TTTGATCTCAAGGCTT-1-H0025_apex 1
TTTGGAGAGTTTGAGA-1-H0025_apex
TTTGATCTCAAGGCTT-1-H0025_apex 2
TTTGGTTCAAGTGACG-1-H0025_apex
TTTGACTCATCCGATA-1-H0025_apex 2
TTTGTTGCAACATACC-1-H0025_apex
TTTGACTCATCCGATA-1-H0025_apex 3
AAACCCAAGCATATGA-1-H0025_LA
TTTGATCTCAAGGCTT-1-H0025_apex 3
AAACCCACACACTTAG-1-H0025_LA
AAACCCATCGCGTAGC-1-H0025_LA
AAACGAAAGTATGTAG-1-H0025_LA
AAACGAAAGTGCACAG-1-H0025_LA
```

Or if the key from column 1 that defines your duplicate is a substring of `$1` you can use `substr`:

```
awk '++cnt[substr($1, character_length_that_defines_key)]<=3' file
```